# It is so pity that you cannot join us now

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I wonder if I can use the following sentence.

> It is **so** pity that you cannot join us now.

---

I know the causal usage is " it's a pity" or "it is such a pity that...", but  is it also correct and casual  to use "so" before pity as if it is a "so-that" structure?

Comment: "So pity" sounds like [Doge](http://the-toast.net/2014/02/06/linguist-explains-grammar-doge-wow/) to me because, as the answers explain, pity doesn't have a degree. *very grammar. much confuse. wow, English.* ;) I hope the article I linked explaining how to create Doge phrases will be helpful in understanding how so, much, many, et. al. are used in English (and maybe be interesting at the same time). I would probably say "It's so unfortunate" or "It's so sad" if I didn't want to use "such a pity".

Comment: Pitiful is an adjective, but "It is so pitiful that you..." has a different meaning and is a bit insulting.

Comment: @stannius There's also 'pitiable' - which is a little bit better to my ear, but really isn't an improvement on the idiomatic 'it is such a pity ...' at all

Comment: You could say "so pitiful", but it would come off as mean or condescending.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Used in this context, [so](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so) is an adverb of degree, meaning **very, extremely, or to such a degree**. Adverbs of degree are used to qualify adjectives- **so good**, **so nice**, etc., or other adverbs- **so nicely**.

[pity](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pity) is a noun: you cannot use an adverb to qualify a noun. You need to use a predeterminer + determiner sequence like **such a** to qualify a noun.

Answer (score 6):

Pity is not usually used as an adjective. It can be used as a noun (as in your examples), or also as a verb ("I pity you").

Probably the best way to say what you want to say is "It is such a pity that you cannot join us now". Don't ask me why that is correct though :)

Comment: The right answer, but i would add that point out that a native speaker would *never* say "It's so pity that ...".

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use it that way. And it will probably be understood. But only AFTER getting over the fact that it is NOT conventional native usage. It very much marks the sentence as being constructed by a non-English speaker.

Others have given several technical explanations of why it is not proper English usage.

Answer (score -1):

We use *pity* as a noun or a verb but not an adjective.  *So* is used before adjectives.  You should not say:

> *You are **so boy**.

This is ungrammatical because *boy* is a noun, not an adjective.  The same is true of *pity*:

> *It is **so pity** that you cannot join us now.

Since *pity* is not an adjective, this too is ungrammatical.

Instead of saying *so boy*, form an adjective from *boy* and say *boyish*.  It would be correct to say:

> You are **so boyish**.

In the same way, form an adjective from *pity* and say *pitiful*. It would be correct to say:

> It is **so pitiful** that you cannot join us now.

---

In this answer, the * symbol marks an utterance as ungrammatical.